# How i can add not null field into an existing table, where as existing table contains a number of records

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, migration

1. I have an existing Db table (PostgreSQL) with the number records.
2. I need to add a new column with NOT NULL constraints using Laravel migrations.

Note: I don't want to lose my existing table data.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to ensure that all other rows do not have nulls in your desired column.

Then before `ALTER TABLE` you will need to backfill values of already existing rows if you have nulls.

However you might find yourself in situation when nulls are desirable in some specific situation (for example you are introducing STI). Then instead of not null constraint you can use regular constraint that makes column not null depending on other column.

For example you might have some already exisiting status that may have null variable and it is ok to have it. Then you might want to use custom constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE invoices ADD CHECK (((customer_id IS NOT NULL) OR (status = 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use artisan commands to attach a new column to the existing table, for example you could run this command: `php artisan make:migration add_column_name_to_tablename_table`, and then within the migration file, you could define the column name and associate properties. Then you could run `php artisan migrate` to reflect the change

Answer (score 0):

You can go for default value 0.

```
Schema::table('yourTable', function ($table) {
    $table->integer('active')->default(0)->change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's really helpfull.

Comment: You are welcome. You can rate me by answered this question